# Adding data from a query to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a query in viewDidLoad and viewDidScroll that updates some NSMutableDictionary and gets me the data for my UICollectionView.

But in the following function, the data is nil/null.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger i = indexPath.row;

    NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int) i];

    // The following 2 lines are nil
    NSString *objectId = _obj[test];
    // Get the object
    PFObject *data = _photos[objectId];

    ,,,
```

How do I get the collection view to "wait" for that data and/or add a loading... to the cell box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this when your data for the collection view is ready:

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I just figured that out.